# ggplot summarise mean value of categorical variable on y axis

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, seaborn

I am trying to replicate a Python plot in R that I found in this Kaggle notebook: [Titanic Data Science Solutions](https://www.kaggle.com/startupsci/titanic-data-science-solutions)

This is the Python code to generate the plot, the dataset used can be found [here](https://github.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/blob/master/titanic.csv):

```py
import seaborn as sns
...

grid = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, row='Embarked', size=2.2, aspect=1.6)
grid.map(sns.pointplot, 'Pclass', 'Survived', 'Sex', palette='deep')
grid.add_legend()
```

Here is the [resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVhYi.png).

[image: Seaborn Plot]

The `survival` column takes values of 0 and 1 (survive or not survive) and the y-axis is displaying the mean per `pclass`. When searching for a way to calculate the mean using `ggplot2`, I usually find the `stat_summary()` function. The best I could do was this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
...

train_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Pclass), y = Survived, group = Sex, colour = Sex)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") +
  facet_grid(Embarked ~ .)
```

The output can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogjC8.png).

[image: R Plot Output]

There are some issues:

- There seems to be an empty facet, maybe from NA's in Embarked?
- The points don't align with the line
- The lines are different than those in the Python plot

I think I also haven't fully grasped the layering concept of ggplot. I would like to separate the `geom = "line"` in the `stat_summary()` function and rather add it as a `+ geom_line()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually an empty level (i.e. `""`) in `train_df$Embarked`. You can filter that out before plotting.

```
train_df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/master/titanic.csv')
train_df <- subset(train_df, Embarked != "")

ggplot(train_df, aes(x = factor(Pclass), y = Survived, group = Sex, colour = Sex)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = 'mean_cl_boot') +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = mean) +
  facet_grid(Embarked ~ .)
```

You can replicate the python plot by drawing confidence intervals using `stat_summary`. Although your lines with `stat_summary` were great, I've rewritten it as a `geom_line` call, as you asked.

Note that your ggplot code doesn't draw any points, so I can't answer that part, but probably you were drawing the raw values which are just many 0s and 1s.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! At first glance I didn't understand what fun.data = 'mean_cl_boot' does, but i found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414565/interpretation-of-stat-summary-mean-cl-boot-at-ggplot2#answer-17415067